# Remove Graph from AMStockChart

Tags: amcharts

I am adding and removing graphs from my AMStock chart, using the following code:      `stockPanel.removeGraph(graphToRemove);` where stockPanel is the panel I am using to manage the graphs, when I execute this method, the graph is removed from the chart, however when I want to add another graph, I am calling chart.validateData() and this is causing the removed graph to appear again. It seems that the graph is stuck somewhere in the chart, and is reappearing on the call of ValidateData();

Note: I also tried to remove the graph directly using `stockPanel.graphs.splice(graphIndex, 1);`, but it didn't work either.

Comment: This looks like a bug. I work for amCharts and have forwarded this to development. We'll notify you here when it's fixed.

Comment: Thanks, is there a workaround we can us for now

Comment: Not that I know of. Sorry.

Comment: You should use panel.removeStockGraph instead of panel.removeGraph. And also, chart.validateData() or chart.validateNow() should be called after removeGraph in order this to take effect.

Comment: I tried but didnt work, thanks

Comment: Did you ever fix this? i'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @Puzzle84, Unfortunately no, due to change in requirements, what i am doing now is to reinitialize the whole chart when removing a graph, so if I have 4 graphs, and i want to remove one, I am removing all 4 (by calling chart.clear()) and then adding the remaining 3.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what i did was. hide the graphs.

```
public toggleGraph = (graph, toggle) => {
    if(toggle) {
        this.amchart.showGraph(graph);
        graph.visibleInLegend = toggle;
    } else {
        this.amchart.hideGraph(graph);
        graph.visibleInLegend = toggle;
    }
        this.amchart.validateNow();
}
```

Remember to use this.amchart.validateNow();

Remove graphs works too aslong as you make sure it's not being used by the scrollbar. so i set it to undefined.
and then go loop over my graphs and see which one is the first one visibleinLegend and then show that one.

Hope this helps dude!